# Receber uma propriedade de um spring form anotada com @SessionScope

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Tenho um formulário Spring para fazer login no sistema. Esse login deve ser mantido em sessão, então anotei a `classe Credencial` (equivalente a login) com `@SessionScope`. 
Eu recebo os dados dessa credencial do formulário de login, só que quando está anotado com `@SessionScope`, os valores do formulário não são recebidos pelo método.

**Classe Credencial:**

```
@SessionScope
@Component
public class Credencial {

    @CodigoFuncional(message="O valor informado não é um código funcional!")
    private String codigoFuncional;

    @Size(min=7, message="A senha deve ter pelo menos 7 caracteres")
    private String senha;

    private String nome;

    private int juncao; 

    private boolean ativo;

    public Credencial() {}

    public Credencial(String codigoFuncional, String nome,
            int juncao, boolean ativo) {
        this.codigoFuncional = codigoFuncional;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.juncao = juncao;
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }

    public String getCodigoFuncional() {
        return codigoFuncional;
    }

    public void setCodigoFuncional(String codigoFuncional) {
        this.codigoFuncional = codigoFuncional;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getJuncao() {
        return juncao;
    }

    public void setJuncao(int juncao) {
        this.juncao = juncao;
    }

    public boolean isAtivo() {
        return ativo;
    }

    public void setAtivo(boolean ativo) {
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }

}
```

**Classe Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
//@SessionAttributes("credencial")
public class CredencialController {

    @Autowired
    private Credencial credencial;

    @PostMapping(value="/validarLogin/")
    @ModelAttribute("credencial")
    public RedirectView efetuarLogin(RedirectAttributes atributos, @Valid @ModelAttribute("credencial") Credencial credencial, BindingResult resultado, ModelMap modelo){

        RedirectView view = new RedirectView();
        if(resultado.hasErrors()){
            view.setUrl("/SCDA/");
            atributos.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.credencial", resultado);
            atributos.addFlashAttribute("credencial", credencial);
        }else{

            if(Utilitario.validaSenha(credencial.getCodigoFuncional(), credencial.getSenha())){
                atributos.addFlashAttribute("credencial", credencialService.captura(credencial.getCodigoFuncional()));
                view.setUrl("/SCDA/inicio/");
            }else{
                view.setUrl("/SCDA/");
                resultado.reject("errorCode", "Usuário e/ou senha incorretos!");
                atributos.addFlashAttribute("credencial", credencial);
                atributos.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.credencial", resultado);
            }
        }   
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Formulário:**

```
<form:form class="m-t" id="form-login" modelAttribute="credencial" name="form-login" role="form" action="/SCDA/validarLogin/" method="POST">
    <form:errors cssClass="erro"/>
    <form:hidden id="senha-encriptada" path="senha" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:input path="codigoFuncional" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Código Funcional" required />
        <form:errors path="codigoFuncional" cssClass="erro"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" id="senha" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha do CORP" />
        <form:errors path="senha" cssClass="erro"/>
    </div>              
    <a href="javascript:validaLogin()" title="Fazer Login" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</a>
```

Quando eu dou o `submit`, o `Spring` não consegue pegar o valor da Credencial quando chama o método, fica tudo nulo. Se eu comento a anotação "`@SessionAttributes`" o `Spring` nem chega nesse método.

Como faço para colocar essa credencial em sessão usando mecanismos do `Spring`? (Sem usar diretamente o `HttpServletRequest.getSession()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola,

Desculpe, não é na classe esta anotação mas em um método separado apenas para fazer o bind dos atributos, ficaria algo parecido

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
@SessionAttributes("credencial")
public class CredencialController {
   . . .

   @PostMapping(value="/validarLogin/")
   public RedirectView efetuarLogin(RedirectAttributes atributos, @Valid @ModelAttribute("credencial") Credencial credencial, BindingResult resultado, ModelMap modelo){
     . . . 
   }

   @ModelAttribute("credencial")
   public Credencial credencial() {
     return new Credencial();
   }
```

Mais um exemplo

https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-session-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Ola

Tente anotar a classe Credencial apenas com @ModelAttribute

```
@ModelAttribute("credencial")
public class Credencial {
```

O método post deve ter apenas o @PostMapping

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-session-attributes

Comment: hmm, quando eu anoto a classe Credencial com @ModelAttribute o compilador reclama que essa anotação não é permitida nessa localização